# Linq to Entity - How to concatenate conditions

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am writing a Linq Query. Is there a way that I can concatenate to query based on some if conditions?

Like on query is

```
    from res in _db.Person
    where res.Departments.ID == deptId
    select res;
```

And if I have a condition true, I would like it to be something like

```
from res in _db.Person
    where res.Departments.ID == deptId && res.Departments.Type == deptType
    select res;
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the logic you require, you've stated you require OR on another comment where do you need the or?

Comment: Use this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512230/where-clause-with-multiple-unknown-conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your condition is in the variable condition

```
from res in _db.Person
where res.Departments.ID == deptId && (!condition || res.Departments.Type == deptType)
select res;
```

Version that does or as requested

```
from res in _db.Person
where res.Departments.ID == deptId || (condition && res.Departments.Type == deptType))
select res;
```

Alternatively you may wish to use [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Implementing an "AND" type condition is easy - and easier using extension method syntax to call `Where` multiple times:

```
IQueryable<Person> people = _db.Person
                               .Where(res => res.Departments.ID == deptId);
if (deptType != null)
{
    people = people.Where(res => res.Departments.Type == deptType);
}

// Potentially add projections etc.
```

EDIT: If you want "OR" functionality, it's slightly tricky from scratch, as you need to mess around with expression trees. I suggest you use the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) library:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool> predicate = res => res.Departments.ID == deptId;
if (deptType != null)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(res => res.Departments.Type == deptType);
}
IQueryable<Person> people = _db.Person.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: i think this will be First-Where AND Second-Where - right?
I need OR

Comment: @eFriend: If you needed OR, why did you have AND in your question? OR is significantly harder to implement.

Comment: was my mistake, sorry. can u suggest OR implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
var result = _db.Person.Where(x=>x.Departments.ID == deptId);
if(myCondition)
   result = result.Where(x=>x.Departments.Type == deptType);
```

The query is not actually executed until you attempt to enumerate `result`, so you can keep adding conditions as long as you like.

Comment: i think this will be First-Where AND Second-Where - right?
I need OR